# Pandas create a new column by applying function that returns dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Goal is to create a new column based on return values of row level information of data frames existing column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf], "B": [10, 20]})

                                             A   B
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  10
1           Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf  20
```

there exist method:

```
def returnTopic(model, query, numberOftopics): 
    # strip out topics per query/row and return topics that are relevant to a query/row
    return topicDict`
```

`topicDict` contain `{'x': ['fox','brown'], 'y':['jumps','over','the']}`

I want to create two new columns from these return elements in the dictionary.

```
                                             A   B  x               y
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  10 ['fox','brown'] ['jumps','over','the']
1           Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf  20
```

Here is my attempt:

`df['x'] = df.apply(lambda x: returnTopic(tmodel['x'], x['A'], 2))`

Comment: Hmm, your question is a bit unclear. Can you please edit `returnTopic` to be a little more in-line with what you are trying to do? The `apply` function should return a result for _each row_, not just a single result, so your expected output doesn't make sense here.

Comment: It only return per row, query is actually each row of the column. I edited to explain. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new DataFrame from records, and concatenate it to the old one.

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
                         'Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf'], "B": [10, 20]})

def f(text, something_else):
    return {'x':len(text), 'y': text.count(' ')}

new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['A'].apply(lambda x: f(x, 0)))], axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

It will return

```
                                             A   B   x  y
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  10  43  8
1           Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf  20  34  6
```

Comment: my function takes more than one argument, yes one argument is row but other two are configuration information such as model object etc..

Comment: This is absolutely okay, if you apply lambda wrapper, as in your original example

Answer (score 2):

Have your function return a `pd.Series` object:

```
def foo(x): 
    ...
    return pd.Series(topicDict)
```

Now, call `apply` along the first axis:

```
v = df.apply(foo, 1)
v
              x                   y
0  [fox, brown]  [jumps, over, the]
1  [fox, brown]  [jumps, over, the]
```

Concatenate the result with the original, using `pd.concat`.

```
pd.concat([df, v], 1)

                                             A   B             x  \
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  10  [fox, brown]   
1           Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf  20  [fox, brown]   

                    y  
0  [jumps, over, the]  
1  [jumps, over, the]
```

Comment: my function takes more than one argument, yes one argument is row but other two are configuration information such as model object etc..

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis That isn't a problem, you can just modify the `apply` call by including a lambda. The core point of my answer is that you should return a series object.